# Xamarin Forms Shell don't show menu bar on detail page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I testing the Xamarin Forms Shell. In the VS 2019 template when you navigate form the master page with the item list to the detail page the menu bar is still visible, which doesn't look right for me. Is there a way I can hide that on the details page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
Shell.TabBarIsVisible = "False"
```

on your details page.